# Javascript insert element into next table td without using ID, Name etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html-table

I want to input some `<p>NewText</p>` into next td after there was some keyup at previous td's input. For example, if the input text field is in the table's second td, then after I make some keyup some `<p>NewText</p>` appears into the table's third td. I want to get it done without ID, Names, Classes etc.

The problem in my code is that `<p>NewText</p>` inserts between second and third td. I don't know how to put inside the third td.

[image]

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Text</td>
        <td><input type="text" onkeyup="scripts(this)" /></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
function scripts($this) {
    $this.parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML = '';

    if ($this.value !== '') {
        $("<p>NewText</p>").insertAfter($this.parentNode);
    };
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: Don't call functions `function`. Once you've fixed that:

jQuery's [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) can take you to the first matching ancestor element, and then [`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) can take you from there to the next sibling. So:

```
function someName(rawElement) {
    var $el = $(rawElement);
    $el.closest('td').next().html("This markup will replace the content of the next cell");
}
```

(Note the first line, since what you're passing into your function isn't a jQuery object, it's a DOM element.)

Answer (score 0):

A function named "function" ? Errr.

Anyway, this should simply work :

```
function function($this) {
    if ($this.value) $this.parentNode.nextSibling.innerHTML = "<p>NewText</p>";
};
```